# What is meant by PDF in describing a distribution? Is a PDF ( or PMF) always also a probability function?

Tags: distributions

I am trying to understand the following statement

> Consider a random variable that follows the distribution
>
> $PDF(Y=y|p) =(1-p)^y p$ 
> where $y \in\{0,1,2 ... \}$ is a non-negative
> integer and p is the parameter of a distribution.

I am familiar with describing a distribution as $p(x|\theta)$ where $\theta$ is a parameter and I am (almost) familiar with a pdf as a probability density function of a distribution. But I am not familiar with a distribution being described as a pdf.  Is this common practice?

[Update] 
I received a correction stating that it should be PMF not PDF to distinguish that the RVs are discrete. But I am still confused.

Is a probability distribution and the PDF (or PMF) of a distribution one and the same thing? Is a distribution defined by it's PDF ?

For example my lecture notes state that the PDF for the normal distribution is 
$f(y_i|\theta : \mu, \sigma^2) = p(y_i | \theta : \mu, \sigma^2)= (\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2})^\frac{1}{2} exp ( - \frac{(y_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}) $

This seems to be different from what whuber is telling me.

My Cheatsheet states that the Gaussian is also this formula.

Comment: Yes it's common: just search our site for "PDF."  But this formula is not a PDF: it's the formula of a *probability function.*  It clearly and thoroughly describes the distribution.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) on 'geometric distribution' (2nd parameterization counting failures before first success).

Comment: Oh dear, I am still confused. I updated the question.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @whuber why do you say that the formula is not a PDF? Because it is a PMF? I was used to seeing the function name written  as P or Pr so it threw me when it was written as PDF

Comment: Yes.  Thomas Lumley has explained it well.

Comment: I guess it looks odd to write $P(Y=y|p)$ hence the use of PMF instead of P?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any one-dimensional probability distribution can be defined by its **cumulative** distribution function $P(X\leq x)$, and you can specify a model (a set of probability distributions) by letting this depend on parameters, $P(X\leq x; \theta)$

Most of the probability distributions you encounter can *also* be written in terms of either a probability (mass) function or a probability density function.

The probability function (or probability mass function) specifies $P(X=x)$ for any $x$.  If the distribution is discrete, that makes sense and $P(X=x)=P(X\geq x)-P(X>x)$ is uniquely defined. Your example specifies $P(Y=y)$, and so is the probability function of a family of discrete distributions. As @BruceET says, it's the geometric distribution family.

The probability density function is the derivative of the CDF with respect to $x$, so it makes sense if the CDF has a derivative[1]. We usually say these are continuous distributions, though the precise mathematical term is 'absolutely continuous'. In your example of a Gaussian distribution, you are quoting the probability density function. The density function doesn't specify $P(X=x)$, because that is zero. Instead, you need to integrate the density function over a set to find the probability of that set.

There are probability distributions that are neither discrete nor continuous and so have neither a probability function nor a density function. A relatively realistic example is a positive continuous random variable with a discrete spike at zero. These are used in modelling medical cost data.  There are also more mathematically complicated ways a distribution can be neither discrete nor continuous.

Most of this is also true for higher-dimensional variables, though the classification of ways it can go wrong is more complicated. It can also mostly be made true for settings where there isn't an ordering on $X$ (such as compass bearing, which wraps around at $360^{\circ}$.